# Print your Birthday month in a given arranged way in python

Tags: python

Saw a post in FB which is -

write your Birthday month in this way :)

September

Eptember

Ptember

Tember

Ember

Mber

Ber

Er

R

I Want to code this in python, Please help me to get this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: How is this related to "pandas"?

Comment: Well cannot be used it for learning purpose? or for enhancing knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bm = 'September'
for i in range(len(bm)):
    print(bm[i:].capitalize())

September
Eptember
Ptember
Tember
Ember
Mber
Ber
Er
R
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but first letter should be in caps.

Comment: add `.capitalize()`

Answer (score 2):

```
print('September')
print('Eptember')
print('Ptember')
print('Tember')
print('Ember')
print('Mber')
print('Ber')
print('Er')
print('R')
```

Comment: but this is not so efficient, depending on someones b'day month every time I will have to reduce or increase the print statements.